# Matlab Table / Dataset type optimization

Tags: matlab, matrix, data-structures, dataset, tuples

I am searching some optimized datatypes for "observations-variables" table in Matlab, that can be fast and easily accessed by columns (through variables) and by rows (through observations).

Here is сomparison of existing Matlab datatypes:

1. **Matrix** is very fast, hovewer, it has no built-in indexing labels/enumerations for its dimensions, and you can't always remember variable name by column index.
2. **Table** has very bad performance, especially when reading individual rows/columns in a for loop (I suppose it runs some slow convertion methods, and is designed to be more Excel-like).
3. **Scalar structure** (structure of column arrays) datatype - fast column-wise access to variables as vectors, but slow row-wise conversion to observations.
4. **Nonscalar structure** (array of structures) - fast row-wise access to observations as vectors, but slow column-wise conversion to variables.

I wonder if I can use some simpler and optimized version of Table data type, if I want just to combine row-number and column-variable indexing with only numerical variables -OR- any variable type.

Results of test script:

```
----
TEST1 - reading individual observations
Matrix: 0.072519 sec
Table: 18.014 sec
Array of structures: 0.49896 sec
Structure of arrays: 4.3865 sec
----
TEST2 - reading individual variables
Matrix: 0.0047834 sec
Table: 0.0017972 sec
Array of structures: 2.2715 sec
Structure of arrays: 0.0010529 sec
```

Test script:

```
Nobs = 1e5; % number of observations-rows
varNames = {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O'};
Nvar = numel(varNames); % number of variables-colums

M = randn(Nobs, Nvar); % matrix

T = array2table(M, 'VariableNames', varNames); % table

NS = struct; % nonscalar structure = array of structures
for i=1:Nobs
    for v=1:Nvar
        NS(i).(varNames{v}) = M(i,v);
    end
end

SS = struct; % scalar structure = structure of arrays
for v=1:Nvar
    SS.(varNames{v}) = M(:,v);
end

%% TEST 1 - reading individual observations (row-wise)
disp('----'); disp('TEST1 - reading individual observations');

tic; % matrix
for i=1:Nobs
   x = M(i,:); end
disp(['Matrix: ', num2str(toc()), ' sec']);

tic; % table
for i=1:Nobs
   x = T(i,:); end
disp(['Table: ', num2str(toc), ' sec']);

tic;% nonscalar structure = array of structures
for i=1:Nobs
    x = NS(i); end
disp(['Array of structures: ', num2str(toc()), ' sec']);

tic;% scalar structure = structure of arrays 
for i=1:Nobs
    for v=1:Nvar
        x.(varNames{v}) = SS.(varNames{v})(i);
    end
end
disp(['Structure of arrays: ', num2str(toc()), ' sec']);

%% TEST 2 - reading individual variables (column-wise)
disp('----'); disp('TEST2 - reading individual variables');

tic; % matrix
for v=1:Nvar
   x = M(:,v); end
disp(['Matrix: ', num2str(toc()), ' sec']);

tic; % table
for v=1:Nvar
   x = T.(varNames{v}); end
disp(['Table: ', num2str(toc()), ' sec']);

tic; % nonscalar structure = array of structures
for v=1:Nvar
    for i=1:Nobs
        x(i,1) = NS(i).(varNames{v});
    end
end
disp(['Array of structures: ', num2str(toc()), ' sec']);

tic; % scalar structure = structure of arrays
for v=1:Nvar
    x = SS.(varNames{v}); end
disp(['Structure of arrays: ', num2str(toc()), ' sec']);
```

Comment: Timing should be done with [`timeit`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timeit.html) for accurate results. Also, just use a matrix and put in a comment above/behind/below or somewhere what the columns contain. In a function that's usually part of the first comment section, i.e. the one you get when you type `help FunctionName`

Comment: I have checked that, and timing it with `timeit` gives more or less the same result.

Comment: I would have thought gnovice's containers.Map solution would have suited your fancy. That was my initial reaction to the question. The only other thing I could think of is extending a fundamental class like struct.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would use matrices, since they're the fastest and most straightforward to use, and then create a set of enumerated column labels to make indexing columns easier. Here are a few ways to do this:

### Use a [`containers.Map`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/containers.map-class.html) object:

Given your variable names, and assuming they map in order from columns 1 through `N`, you can create a mapping like so:

```
varNames = {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O'};
col = containers.Map(varNames, 1:numel(varNames));
```

And now you can use the map to access columns of your data by variable name. For example, if you want to fetch the columns for variables `A` and `C` (i.e. the first and third) from a matrix `data`, you would do this:

```
subData = data(:, [col('A') col('C')]);
```

### Use a [`struct`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct.html):

You can create a structure with the variable names as its fields and the corresponding column indices as their values like so:

```
enumData = [varNames; num2cell(1:numel(varNames))];
col = struct(enumData{:});
```

And here's what `col` contains:

```
struct with fields:

  A: 1
  B: 2
  C: 3
  D: 4
  E: 5
  F: 6
  G: 7
  H: 8
  I: 9
  J: 10
  K: 11
  L: 12
  M: 13
  N: 14
  O: 15
```

And you would access columns `A` and `C` like so:

```
subData = data(:, [col.A col.C]);
% ...or with dynamic field names...
subData = data(:, [col.('A') col.('C')]);
```

### Make a bunch of variables:

You *could* just create a variable in your workspace for every column name and store the column indices in them. This will pollute your workspace with more variables, but gives you a terse way to access column data. Here's an easy way to do it, using the much-maligned [`eval`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eval.html):

```
enumData = [varNames; num2cell(1:numel(varNames))];
eval(sprintf('%s=%d;', enumData{:}));
```

And accessing columns `A` and `C` is as easy as:

```
subData = data(:, [A C]);
```

### Use an [enumeration class](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/enumerations.html):

This is probably a good dose of overkill, but if you're going to use the same mapping of column labels and indices for *many* analyses you could create an enumeration class, save it somewhere on your [MATLAB path](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/what-is-the-matlab-search-path.html), and never have to worry about defining your column enumerations again. For example, here's a `ColVar` class with 15 enumerated values:

```
classdef ColVar < double
  enumeration
    A (1)
    B (2)
    C (3)
    D (4)
    E (5)
    F (6)
    G (7)
    H (8)
    I (9)
    J (10)
    K (11)
    L (12)
    M (13)
    N (14)
    O (15)
  end
end
```

And you would access columns `A` and `C` like so:

```
subData = data(:, [ColVar.A ColVar.C]);
```

Comment: Thank you for interesting solutions! But in all these cases I will have different matlab variables for enumerated column labels and for dataset itself.  I've tried to inherit from built-in Matlab double class and add a property or enumeration for holding variable names, but it didn't work: "When a subclass of a built-in class defines properties, MATLAB no longer supports indexing and concatenation operations" https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/subclassing-matlab-built-in-classes.html

Comment: @Sairus: True, subclassing a built-in data type would potentially reduce efficiency, since you'd have to implement the indexing and concatenation methods yourself (listed at your link). Still, I'm not clear why these options aren't good enough. If efficiency is critical, a simple matrix seems to be what you want, with the only problem being remembering which column label maps to which index. The above solutions should save you that hassle.

Comment: I am working on a system that sequentally process a bunch of signals to many data sets, and passing many labels to every processing function is quite awkward. Alternatively, I can write data storage class, which holds original matrix and labels structure from your answer, with getting and seting methods (with copy-on-write it should be fast enough). But then my functions will depend on that "core" class structure.
However, I think it is a more common problem of existing Matlab data types to address.