# Matlab categorical table variables: Speed? Use in join keys?

Tags: matlab, performance, join, categorical-data, matlab-table

I've dipping my toe into Matlab's categorical variable pool in the context of Matlab tables.  Actually, I may have wandered into that territory in the past, but if so, it would have been in a relatively superficial manner.

These days, I want to use Matlab code patterns to do what I normally would do in MS Access, e.g., various types of joins and filtering.  Much of my data is categorical, and I've read up on the advantages of using categorical variables in tables.  However, they mostly centre around descriptiveness (over enumerated types) and memory efficiency. I haven't run across mention of speed.  Do categorical variables offer a speed advantage?

I also wonder how advisable it is to use categorical variables when doing various types of joins.  The categorical variables will occupy different tables, so it's not clear to me how equivalence in values is established if such variables are involved in the SQL `ON` clause (which Matlab refers to as a `keys` parameter).

From the dearth of relevant Google hits, it almost seems like I'm in new territory, which to me would be a scary thing.  Lack of documentation of best practices, and the resulting need for trial/error and reverse engineering, requires more time than I can devote, so I'll sadly revert back to using strings.

If anyone can point to online guidance information, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: You might be interested in this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44679592/matlab-table-dataset-type-optimization

Comment: Thanks, EBH.  That's a more general question, which I found interesting to peruse. I realize that there are ways to jury-rig field lookups, but I'm cognizant of the need to weigh the trade-off with using built-in data types (I consider "table" to be built-in, as I don't have to build anything). Some of the trade-offs include having to use a map to translate familiar names to column indexes, and the limitations of a uniform-type 2D array. If you modify the columns, you also need to keep in mind the bookkeeping ot update the lookup table for column indices.

Comment: Part of why I posed the question in the manner above, rather than talk about work-arounds, was that I wanted to avoid the more complex code for the latter.  But I was also wondering how equivalences where recognized between two categorical variables, e.g., if a column from one table had values 'cat', 'dog', 'mouse', but a column from another table had values 'dog', 'horse', 'whale'. Would 'dog' in the former be considered equal to 'dog' in the latter?  That determines the behaviour of table joins and lookups.

Comment: And would there be speed penalty for using more readable categorical variables compared to straight integer enumeration of the categories?  This relevance of this last question extends beyond table joins/lookups, but so does the preceding question above. I thought it was not great that newbies to categorical variables have to undertake a characterization of categorical variables before getting to know the intimately. I was hoping that this characterization would be available in order to inform the decision to spend time getting to know catergorical variables.

Comment: I don’t know why you worry about these things. Yes, an int is going to be faster than a categorical areay because (1) int is a native type and the other is a user class, and (2) there’s always a comparison of categories involved before the values themselves can be compared. These values first need to be mapped to a common set of categories. But neither of these things are going to inform the choice of most users. Pick the syntax that makes your code most readable and maintainable. That is way more important than any small differences in execution time. If you care about speed, use C++.

Comment: I worry about these things because you have to know what is considered equivalent before you can decide whether to use categorical variables as keys in any of the join or split/apply workflows. This should be reversed-engineered.  it should be specified up front so that users can be confident of guaranteed behaviour. So should any speed penalties.

Comment: For speed, C++ is inaccessible unless you've already invested the time to be current with it.  That comes with very real and nontrivial trade-offs with other demands.  The decision on whether to do that depends on one's specific walk in life and personal & professional situation.  It goes well beyond the scope of this question.  The whole point of using the Matlab tools is to leverage those tools, and to understand the limits to which they can be pushed.  Compared to ramping up on C++, it would be less onerous to simply deal with integers and live with the reduced readability.

Answer (score 1):

A partial answer only....

The following test indicates that catgorized data behaves sensibly when used as join keys:

```
BigList = {'dog' 'cat' 'mouse' 'horse' 'rat'}'
SmallList = BigList( 1 : end-2 )

Nrows = 20;

% Create tables for innerjoin using strings

tBig = table( ...
    (1:Nrows)' , ...
    BigList( ceil( length(BigList) * rand( Nrows , 1 ) ) ) , ...
    'VariableNames' , {'B_ID' 'Animal'} )

tSmall = table( ...
    (1:Nrows)' , ...
    SmallList( ceil( length(SmallList) * rand( Nrows , 1 ) ) ) , ...
    'VariableNames' , {'S_ID' 'Animal'} )

tBigSmall = innerjoin( tBig , tSmall , 'Keys','Animal' );
tBig = sortrows( tBig , {'Animal','B_ID'} );
tSmall = sortrows( tSmall, {'Animal','S_ID'} );
tBigSmall = sortrows( tBigSmall, {'Animal' 'B_ID' 'S_ID'} );

% Now innerjoin the same tables using categorized strings

tcBig = tBig;
tcBig.cAnimal = categorical( tcBig.Animal );
tcBig.Animal = [];

tcSmall = tSmall;
tcSmall.cAnimal = categorical( tcSmall.Animal );
tcSmall.Animal = [];

tcBigSmall = innerjoin( tcBig , tcSmall , 'Keys','cAnimal' );
tcBig = sortrows( tcBig , {'cAnimal','B_ID'} );
tcSmall = sortrows( tcSmall, {'cAnimal','S_ID'} );
tcBigSmall = sortrows( tcBigSmall, {'cAnimal' 'B_ID' 'S_ID'} );

% Check if the join results are the same

if all( tBigSmall.Animal == tcBigSmall.cAnimal )
    disp('categorical vs string key: inner joins MATCH.')
else
    disp('categorical vs string key: inner joins DO NOT MATCH.')
end % if
```

So the only question now is about speed.  This is a general question, not just for joins, so I'm not sure what would be a good test.  There are many possibilities, e.g., number of table rows, number of categories, whether it's a join or a filtering, etc.

In any case, I believe that the answers to both question would be better documented.

Comment: I wanted to add to this that you can only join on ordinal categorical fields (e.g. `categorical(...,'ordinal',true)`) if the underlying ordering of the categories of the two fields are the same.